# Convert long to char array and back

Tags: programming, variables

I'm trying to store a state in my data logger. I can read/write fine to SD, but I can't wrap my head around reading/writing a `long` value correctly - I've build it down to converting it to char array and back.

My best try so far has been

```
long temp = 1418172669L;
unsigned char buf[4];
buf[0] = temp         & 0xFF;
buf[1] = (temp >>  8) & 0xFF;
buf[2] = (temp >> 16) & 0xFF;
buf[3] = (temp >> 24) & 0xFF;

long  l = buf[0] | (buf[1] << 8) | (buf[2] << 16) | (buf[3] << 24);
```

But `l` is very different from `temp` - currently the output is `-26371`. Am I making an obvious mistake?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suggest using a union:

```
union {
    char myByte[4];
    long mylong;
} foo;
```

**Char to Long:**

Then you can just add the bytes:

```
foo myUnion;
myUnion.myByte[0] = buf[0];
myUnion.myByte[1] = buf[1];
myUnion.myByte[2] = buf[2];
myUnion.myByte[3] = buf[3];
```

Then you can access the long as:

```
myUnion.myLong;
```

**Long to Char:**

The same if you want to go the other way from long to char array:

```
foo myUnion
myUnion.myLong = 1234L;
```

To access bytes:

```
myUnion.myByte[0];
myUnion.myByte[1];
myUnion.myByte[2];
myUnion.myByte[3];
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked great (for longs, not for floats). Can you give me a documentation link for `union`?

Comment: @LordT: I don't know why I used float as an example, I must have misread. I have no link to a "documentation" page, but this is a tutorial/example I think is good: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_unions.htm

Answer (score 1):

I think the last expression is performed exclusively as an `int` expression and converted to `long` only at the end, i.e. before assignment to `l`.

```
long  l = buf[0] | (buf[1] << 8) | (buf[2] << 16) | (buf[3] << 24);
```

Here the compiler calculates `buf[0] | (buf[1] << 8) | (buf[2] << 16) | (buf[3] << 24)` as an `int` only.

If you give a hint to the compiler by telling it you want `long` expressions used, then it should work. The easiest way to do so is to replace the number of bits to be shifted as **long literals**:

```
long  l = buf[0] | (buf[1] << 8L) | (buf[2] << 16L) | (buf[3] << 24L);
```

That should be enough for the compiler to perform the whole operation as `long` and not loose precision.

Comment: Sorry, even with the implicit long, the result is -26371.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, after posting this, I've found another way around it, but @Phataas solution is much more elegant.
Using the `ltoa` and `atol` functions, long to char array and vice-verse can be done like this:

```
char temp[10];
ltoa(669L,temp,10);
long result = atol(temp);
```

Comment: It is also a lot more inefficient.

Comment: Yes, it is - but if you're goal is to write a text file to SD card, it beats the binary approach. I've ended up using a combination of the byte conversion with union and the ltoa version for printing to log files